# How to annotate a code block in Java

Tags: java, annotations, block

Is it possible to annotate a block of code? E.g. for cycle or simply curly brackets? If so, how?

**First.java**

```
package An;
import An.ForCycle;

class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First f = new First();
    }

    public First () {

        @ForCycle
        {   // error: illegal start of type {
            int k;
        }

        @ForCycle
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   // similar error (illegal start...)
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**ForCycle.java**

```
package An;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ForCycle {}
```

According to http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/java-annotations-tutorial-with-custom-annotation.html

> @Target – indicates the kinds of program element to which an annotation type is applicable. Some possible values are TYPE, METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD etc. If Target meta-annotation is not present, then annotation can be used on any program element.

Any program element (I guess) means also block, doesn't it? So why I can't annotate **block** or **for**? What am I missing?

Thanks for help

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to annotate a block? Can't we achieve that using comment?

Comment: @fajarkoe I write an alternative auto-parallelizing preprocessor using ANTLR as a AST tree parser. Java8 grammar can recognize annotations but of course no comments. I intended to someshing like

`@parallel
for (..) {...}`

Comment: Anyone know about the status of JSR308 that seems to want to do exactly what the questioner wants? https://code.google.com/p/jsr308-langtools/wiki/AnnotationsOnStatements

Comment: Did you get any alternative here? Other than using annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "any program element **out of those already listed**".

For the final word on the matter, one simply refers to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7):

> Annotations may be used as modifiers in any declaration, whether package, class (including enums), interface (including annotation types), field, method, formal parameter, constructor, or local variable.
>
> Annotations may also be used on enum constants.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot do this. Actually you have already answered your question yourself. There is a close list of targets where annotation can be used: `{TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE}`. As you can see there is not such thing as "block". Why? Probably because annotation must be attached to something named, e.g. method, field, class etc.

Indeed think about how can use use the annotation? Annotations are accessed using reflection API. You can request annotations of specific method or field. How are you expecting to request annotation of block?

And the last notice. Annotations can be used at runtime or at compile time. Annotations available at compile time are used by compilers, IDEs and annotation processors to generate additional warnings, errors or code. IntelliJ as a well-known IDE with bunch of static code analysis features supports so called "block annotations" that syntactically are regular inline comments but are treated by IDE as annotations that can suppress some warnings.

Answer (score 1):

"Any program element" means here "from the specified list" connotation ie "the default is ALL values" this statement is saying.

In general this is impossible because only compiler works with blocks of code and crunching all that blocks into bytescodes mixed in complex way. There is just no possible usage for such annotation except compilation guidelines

Comment: There could be tons of uses for block-level annotations, like transactions, logging, access control, you name it.

Comment: @DaveNewton With the exception of compile-only annotations such as `@SuppressWarnings`, how would a framework read block-level annotations? If some piece of code is important enough for a pointcut, it's important enough to have a method.

Comment: @chrylis Those are two entirely separate points. *How* isn't really relevant, since we're talking about a hypothetical situation, but anything *could* be represented. The second is *should* it be done this way, and I would tend to agree, but can also see potential uses.